# Did VueJS remove params & paramWatchers in Vue 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-directives

I accidentally found this [documentation of Vue v1](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html#params), which had a feature to watch attributes on the element that the directive is bound to :

`<div v-example v-bind:a="someValue"></div>`

```
Vue.directive('example', {
  params: ['a'],
  paramWatchers: {
    a: function (val, oldVal) {
      console.log('a changed!')
    }
  }
})
```

I am building a custom directive library using Vue 2.7. and I was looking for a similar feature, but it's now missing in the [latest documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/custom-directives.html).

Anyway I have implemented a different logic using `update` hook where I need to programmatically extract attributes from the element.

```
const myDirective: DirectiveOptions = {
  update (el: any, binding: any) {
    const customAttribute = el.getAttribute('customAttribute')
    doSomething(customAttribute)
  }
}
```

But it's not perfectly match with the requirement as the `update` hook is triggering unnecessarily with other elements under the same parent. So this function executes multiple times unnecessarily and also I need to do some hacks to keep state of the directive.

My question is: Is this feature still available somewhere else now? or did Vue introduce a different feature to achieve the same requirement?

Please note that my project is just a set of Directives only, so it doesn't have access to components or root level to place a regular watchers to check for state changes.

Comment: If you're using Vue 2.7, you're looking for [these docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive). The latest docs you linked are for Vue 3 instead.

Comment: You should also be able to skip unnecessary work on duplicate calls by comparing the third and fourth [arguments of the directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive#Directive-Hook-Arguments), `vnode` and `oldVnode` respectively.